# Android ExoPlayer 2 - How to reduce resolution of video before playing?

Tags: android, video, exoplayer2.x

I'm trying to create an Android app that renders multiple videos simultaneously. On my phone, I tried with 2 4k videos and the app started lagging. However, when I reduced the resolution down to fullHD yet keeping the same bitrate, app performed much better.

Is there a way to lower the resolution of the original video before exoplayer actually loading and playing the video? Something likes handling bitmap for images: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/graphics

I don't want to use ffmpeg because my app needs to play the downloaded videos as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The processing required to transcode to a lower bitrate is likely to be similar or more than the processing required to play back the video, so I am not sure that trying to reduce the resolution the device itself will really help you.

If your videos are being streamed from a server then a streaming protocol like HLS or DASH will typically provide multiple different bit rates/resolutions for the video and you can select in the player one of the lower resolutions, the same as picking quality level on YouTube etc.

If you have many different video then another approach is to combine the videos into a single stream on the server side and then send that single stream to the device. You can then allow a user to expand or 'move to stage' a particular video by using a touch grid over the combined video and adding a second stream for the selected video if a user selects it.

Comment: Basically, my app holds videos on memory and not does any streaming stuff. From what I've tested, reducing resolution not only help app less lagging, but also avoid out of memory crash since JVM consume less memory. Reducing bitrate seems not helping as reducing resolution. As for images, sampling bitmap technique helps reducing memory taken when loading. Therefore, I think there might be a same way for videos. Indeed ffmpeg helps, but it will take a moment to create another video, while I wish "the resize process" could happen when the video is loading to the player.

Comment: @HoàiVũLê, do you download the videos to the app or are they recorded from the device camera by the user? If they are downloaded you can do the transcoding to a lower resolution on the server side before downloading.

Comment: My app downloads videos. I will try your suggestion!